# What are some best open source software alternative for popular proprietary softwares like Photoshop and inDesign and so on?

Tags: windows, linux, open-source

What are some of the best and free alternatives for softwares like adobe photoshop/adobe indesign/ adobe premier/MS office/ vmware?

Comment: These are too many requests in one question

Comment: Much too broad a question for a Stack Exchange. This site is aimed at narrowly-focused questions about a specific need.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154).

Comment: Take a look at http://alternativeto.net/ But, pelase learn [ask] questions.

Answer (score 5):

- [shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/)(alternative for adobe premier)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - video editor
- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) (alternative for adobe photoshop)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - graphic editor
- [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) (alternative for adobe illustrator)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - vector graphics editor
- [scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) (alternative for adobe inDesign and Microsoft pulisher)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - desktop publishing application
- [goldendict](http://goldendict.org/) (alternative for babylon)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - dictionary
- [libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)/[openoffice](https://www.openoffice.org/) (alternative for MS office)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - office suite
- [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - video transcoder
- [aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - create and edit subtitle
- [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org) (alternative for vmware)

  - free
  - open source
  - cross-platform
  - hypervisor